# org-mode: Why do my images look pixelated?

Tags: org-mode, images, inline-image, imagemagick

Why do my images look pixelated?

My guess is the problem is with the resizing algorithm. It needs more antialiasing or more DPI or something. Is there any way I can improve that?

org-mode:
[image]

Original:
[image]

Here is the complete text of the org-mode file, though this happens with all images in every file (and so this info doesn't really matter):

- The image file: https://files.lilf.ir/tmp/20240111_105923_TIIbBt.jpg

```
#+TITLE: bootstrap

* [[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)][Bootstrapping (statistics) - Wikipedia]]

* [[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_aggregating][Bootstrap aggregating - Wikipedia]]
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 629
[[file:gen.org_imgs/20240111_105923_TIIbBt.jpg]]

** ML Dr. Jafari
#+ATTR_HTML: :width 900
[[file:gen.org_imgs/20240111_035644_BCth5p.jpg]]
```

Comment: That looks fine to me. Can you be more specific about the problem?

Comment: @db48x The boundaries of the different colors are blurred

Comment: If you say so. I can’t see anything wrong. Why don’t you take a screenshot of _just_ the problem, and nothing else. Maybe even zoom in on it.

Comment: Or maybe even better, provide the Org mode file itself and any instructions necessary to reproduce the problem, so that *we* can try it out and see for ourselves.

Comment: @NickD It isn't a problem that happens with any one specific image. It happens with all images. (I guess if the image has no text, it's not noticeable.) The problem is not too bad, but the image quality is just not as good as when I view the images with any other app, and the image looks slightly blurry and pixely. Here is an example image I tested with: https://files.lilf.ir/tmp/20240112_210226_iP8AZc.jpg

Comment: The link does not work for me. However,  I can  (and did) download the image from Wikipedia and write a short Org mode file, inline the image and look for problems. It may be my eyes, but I don't see *any* problem. So I would like you to *tell* me how to reproduce the problem, so I can try it and be reasonably certain that I'm not going off the rails. *That's* what I suggested.

Comment: @NickD I don't know why the link wouldn't work for you, it still works for me. I don't know what else I can do to make the problem more reproduceable. It might be the OS/display, too (I am on a Retina display Apple machine). Regardless of its reproducibility, do you know how emacs re-sizes images to be displayed? I am pretty sure that the problem is in that step. It is resizing the image using a naive algorithm and the quality suffers.

Comment: You need to include more information: in particular, you need to include your Org mode file (*not* a screen shot of it): we need to see the *text* of the file, including all the links.

Comment: @NickD I added the file and the exact image file used in it. But the file and the image really don't matter. I can see the quality degradation on all images that have some text in it. The text becomes less sharp in emacs compared to viewing the same image with another app.

Comment: Well, I cannot see the quality degradation when I open the WIkipedia image in emacs and ImageMagick, either in the original SVG or after I convert the SVG to JPG or PNG, so I needed your help in order to try to figure out what's going on, but here we are 10 comments into a fruitless discussion and I still cannot even begin to reproduce the problem. So I give up: I  hope that you solve the problem yourself or somebody else can help you solve it. I'll keep watching the question to see how it is resolved.

Comment: Does the image look blurry already in org-mode? Or only after you are zooming in again? I only notice it in the zoomed in image, where it makes total sense. Anyway, if it really looks bad, then I guess it must be the [transform-smoothing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Image-Descriptors.html) algorithm (which apparently is platform dependent). So I guess you could try setting `image-transform-smoothing` to nil. Although irrelevant, I wonder how (or more why) you 'acquired' the jpg version of the image.

Comment: @dalanicolai It doesn't look too bad, it's just looks off putting enough to be a bother. It looks bad in org-mode without zooming in. The jpg version is from saving the content of the clipboard image using Applescript IIRC. Thanks. `image--transform-smoothing` is already `nil` for me. Trying to set it to `smooth` in an org-mode buffer using `image-transform-set-smoothing` errors and says that I am not in an Image buffer.

Comment: @NickD Thanks, Nick.

Comment: Don't use `image-transform-set-smoothing`, indeed that only works for `image-mode`. Just set `image-transform-smoothing` (all single dashes) to nil via `setq` before visiting the org-buffer.

Comment: @dalanicolai I tried both `nil` and `t`. I could not see a difference. Can I set the DPI of the shown image somehow? I just tested another image https://files.lilf.ir/tmp/some_file_3134716dc48147cbab5b5b4a364f9ff8.jpg , and it really has lower quality when viewed in emacs. The image feels as if it had a very lossy compression applied to it.

Comment: Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqs4o.png - the top is the image opened in Emacs, the bottom is the same image displayed by ImageMagick. I don't see any difference. [BTW, I don't know what happened, but the links to `files.lilf.ir` work.] Try using `medianfo` to examine image metadata in the file. You cannot increase the resolution of a raster image (like a JPG): your best bet is to start from a vector image (like an SVG) and convert it to a raster image at the dimensions you are interested in and then leave it alone: no more conversions or resizing.

Comment: That should be `mediainfo`.